# ocalhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 9799

Tags: bigdata

after using this command hdfs namenode -format.

localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 9799 similarly in case of datanode resourcemanager nodemanager.
not able to remove these errors

Comment: Provide more information: some logs, concrete commands you were trying to execute, et cetera.